# Создание многомерного массива по множеству объектов

Tags: php, массивы, ооп

Итак. Есть массив с объектами

```
$arr = array(
    (object)array("name"=>"Имя объекта1", "nameP"=> "" ),
    (object)array("name"=>"Имя объекта2", "nameP"=> "Имя объекта4" ),
    (object)array("name"=>"Имя объекта3", "nameP"=> "Имя объекта1" ),
    (object)array("name"=>"Имя объекта4", "nameP"=> "Имя объекта1" ), 
);
```

где

- `name` - имя объекта.
- `nameP` - имя его родителя.

Нужно сделать так, что бы по этому массиву создало многомерный массив, в котором соблюдалась иерархия массивов:

```
<?php

Имя объекта1(
    Имя объекта => Имя объекта1
    Дети => (
        Имя объекта3
            Имя объекта => Имя объекта3
            Дети => ()
        Имя объекта4
            Имя объекта => Имя объекта4
            Дети => (
                Имя объекта2
                    Имя объекта => Имя объекта2
                    Дети => ()
            )
    )
)
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском. Я вам там немного подправил форматирование, можете нажать [edit] и посмотреть, как это делается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ООП вариант:

1) Простой класс предоставляющий метод addChild и возможность конвертнуть себя в массив:

```
class TreeNode {
        public $id;
        public $parent;
        private $children;

        public function __construct($dataArray) {
                $this->id = $dataArray['id'];
                $this->parent = $dataArray['sub'];
                $this->children = array();
        }

        public function addChild(TreeNode $node) {
                $this->children[$node->id] = $node;
        }

        public function toArray() {
                return array(
                        'id'  => $this->id,
                        'sub' => $this->parent,
                        'children' => array_map(
                           function(TreeNode $element) { 
                             return $element->toArray();
                           }, $this->children
                         )
                );
        }
}
```

2)создаем массив `TreeNodes`:

```
$nodes = array();
$rootNodes = array();
foreach($ar as $arr) {
        $nodes[$ar['id']] = new TreeNode($ar);
        if ($ar['sub'] == 0) {
                $rootNodes[] = $nodes[$ar['id']];
        }
}
```

3)добавление потомков в дерево:

```
array_map(
  function(TreeNode $element) use($nodes){ 
    if(isset($nodes[$element->parent])) 
      $nodes[$element->parent]->addChild($element);
  }, $nodes
);
```

4) конвертирование дерева в массив:

```
print_r(array_map(
  function(TreeNode $element) { 
    return $element->toArray();
  }, $rootNodes)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Если массив с объектами создавали не мы, то для удобства обработки его следует дополнить списком дочерних элементов. И при выводе результата использовать print_r() вместо var_dump().

Программа:

```
$arr = [
    (object)["name"=>"Имя объекта1","nameP"=> ""], 
    (object)["name"=>"Имя объекта2","nameP"=> "Имя объекта4"], 
    (object)["name"=>"Имя объекта3","nameP"=> "Имя объекта1"], 
    (object)["name"=>"Имя объекта4","nameP"=> "Имя объекта1"]
];

function children(&$arr){
    $arr2 = $arr;
    foreach($arr as $key=>&$item){
        if($item->nameP == ""){
            $root = $key;
        } 
        $item->children = [];
        foreach($arr2 as $key2=>$item2){
            if($item2->nameP == $item->name){
                array_push($item->children, $key2);
            }
        }

    }
    return $root;
};

function get_struct($arr, $index){
    $node = $arr[$index];
    struct == [];
    $struct[$node->name] = [
        "Имя объекта" => $node->name,
        "Дети" => []
    ];
    foreach($node->children as $child){
        $struct[$node->name]["Дети"][$arr[$child]->name] = get_struct($arr, $child);
    }
    return $struct;
}

var_dump($arr);
$root = children($arr);
var_dump($arr);
$struct = get_struct($arr, $root);

print("<pre>");
print_r($struct);
print("</pre>");
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'name' => string 'Имя объекта1' (length=22)
      public 'nameP' => string '' (length=0)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'name' => string 'Имя объекта2' (length=22)
      public 'nameP' => string 'Имя объекта4' (length=22)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'name' => string 'Имя объекта3' (length=22)
      public 'nameP' => string 'Имя объекта1' (length=22)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'name' => string 'Имя объекта4' (length=22)
      public 'nameP' => string 'Имя объекта1' (length=22)
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'name' => string 'Имя объекта1' (length=22)
      public 'nameP' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => int 2
          1 => int 3
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'name' => string 'Имя объекта2' (length=22)
      public 'nameP' => string 'Имя объекта4' (length=22)
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'name' => string 'Имя объекта3' (length=22)
      public 'nameP' => string 'Имя объекта1' (length=22)
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[4]
      public 'name' => string 'Имя объекта4' (length=22)
      public 'nameP' => string 'Имя объекта1' (length=22)
      public 'children' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => int 1
Array
(
    [Имя объекта1] => Array
        (
            [Имя объекта] => Имя объекта1
            [Дети] => Array
                (
                    [Имя объекта3] => Array
                        (
                            [Имя объекта3] => Array
                                (
                                    [Имя объекта] => Имя объекта3
                                    [Дети] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [Имя объекта4] => Array
                        (
                            [Имя объекта4] => Array
                                (
                                    [Имя объекта] => Имя объекта4
                                    [Дети] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Имя объекта2] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [Имя объекта2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [Имя объекта] => Имя объекта2
                                                            [Дети] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```